# MusicKitJs: unable to play songs from custom list

Tags: jquery, node.js, itunes, apple-musickit

I am trying to play songs from my API in M4A format and iTunes link. I don't want the user to login to iTunes to play the song. Is it possible?

Also when I am adding the song, either single or in queue, I am getting an error:

> musickit.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) CONTENT_UNAVAILABLE: The requested content is not available.
>       at API. (https://js-cdn.music.apple.com/musickit/v1/musickit.js:1:95138)
>       at https://js-cdn.music.apple.com/musickit/v1/musickit.js:1:14425
>       at Object.next (https://js-cdn.music.apple.com/musickit/v1/musickit.js:1:14530)
>       at fulfilled (https://js-cdn.music.apple.com/musickit/v1/musickit.js:1:13248)

```html
<script src="https://js-cdn.music.apple.com/musickit/v1/musickit.js"></script>
```

```js
var music = MusicKit.getInstance();
var song_url = "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/apple-assets-us-std-000001/Music/2f/4a/3f/mzm.ixudilzh.aac.p.m4a";
music.setQueue({ song: song_url }).then(function(queue) {
  music.play();
});
```

Comment: From reading the documentation it would appear the user needs to authenticate with iTunes before being able to access the music: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/musickitjs

Comment: What about the others